# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \ln(3n+7) - \ln(n)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

The reason why I'm having trouble with this problem is because it involves natural log (ln) and I need to find the limit.

I need to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(3n+7)-\ln(n)$.

I noticed that as $n$ approaches infinity, $-\ln(n)$ should be approaching $-\infty$ but I'm having trouble finding the limit since $\ln(3n+7)$ is in the sequence.

Answer (score 7):

Hint:
$$\ln(x) - \ln(y) = \ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$

Edit:
$$\ln(3n + 7) - \ln(n) = \ln\left(\frac{3n+7}{n}\right) = \ln\left(3 + \frac7n\right)$$

$$\text{If }\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac7n = 0\text{, what remains?}$$

Comment: So I rewrote the sequence as ln((3n+7)/n) but I'm still not sure what the limit would be. I plugged in numbers for n to find the first few terms and I was getting results closer to one but it appears that is not working.

Comment: Would it be that ln(3+0) is what remains since limn→∞7n=0?

Comment: @JMartinez, Exactly! Notice that it's near impossible to guess the convergence of a sequence based on any patterns in the first few terms. I think you'll find this function doesn't tend to $1$

Comment: Yea I noticed that it doesn't tend to 1 but 1.098612289

Comment: @JMartinez, check this out: $\ln(3)>\ln(e) = 1$

Comment: @JMartinez, could you please select the answer if you found it useful?

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\log\left|3n+7\right|-\log\left|n\right|\right),\tag{1}
\end{align}
and if you recall your rules of logarithms, which can be viewed [here](http://mathinsight.org/logarithm_basics) if you need a quick reference (I would highly recommend you take a look as Math Insight is a great site), 
and these allow us to re-write the above as
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\log\left|\frac{3n+7}{n}\right|\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\log\left|3+\frac{7}{n}\right|\right),\tag{2}
\end{align}
and I'm sure you can do the rest...

---

Note: I, personally, use $\log\left|x\right| \Longleftrightarrow \log_{e}\left|x\right|$, but you may also say $\text{ln}\left|x\right|$...